# Dynamic range generation as part of an ARRAYFORMULA calculation

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to write an ARRAYFORMULA that, as part of its calculation, generates a range based on the row the ARRAYFORMULA has written to.

I've tried using ARRAY_CONSTRAIN and ROW:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(K2:K,ROW(K2:K)-1,1)))
```

I've also tried INDIRECT and ROW:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(INDIRECT("K2:K"&ROW(K2:K))))
```

In both cases, it seems that ARRAY_CONSTRAIN and INDIRECT behave as if not inside an ARRAYFORMULA, using only the first value of the array from ROW and so the ARRAYFORMULA does not expand the range.

Is there a way to generate dynamic ranges in an ARRAYFORMULA calculation like this?

EDIT:
If the range K2:K had the following numbers
`2 6 4 8 5 4 2 3`
then a successful outcome would be

```
2
8
12
20
25
29
31
34
```

Comment: Would you please edit your question to provide sample data and an example of a successful outcome.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=scan(,K2:index(K:K,match(,0/(K:K<>""))),lambda(a,c,a+c))
```

[image]